# How to create circular progressbar in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am working with Titanium Appcelerator and I need help in creating Circular progressbar in the app. Can anyone explain me how circular progressbar works and how progress is filled inside circle in circular manner..?

Comment: Take this as a reference: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/378729/MBProgressHUD/5.png

Answer (score 4):

**Please use this Alloy Widget now:** 
https://github.com/manumaticx/circularprogress

---

**Original Answer**

I know this is a little late, but I figured this out after about a days work.

- I have not tested on android
- This is not animated as I did not need it for my needs. To make it animated, look at the second to last line in the function layer3.transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(angle); You should be able to animate the rotation angle.

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%'
    });
    win.open();

```
function circularProgressBar(options)
{
    var opts = options;
    if (opts.percent == null || opts.percent > 1 || opts.percent < 0) opts.percent = 1;
    if (opts.size == null) opts.size = 46;
    if (opts.margin == null) opts.margin = 4;
    if (opts.backgroundColor == null) opts.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    if (opts.progressColor == null) opts.progressColor = '#4ba818';
    if (opts.topper == null) opts.topper = {};
    if (opts.topper.color == null) opts.topper.color = '#fff';
    if (opts.topper.size == null) opts.topper.size = 36;
    if (opts.font == null) opts.font = {};
    if (opts.font.visible == null) opts.font.visible = true;
    if (opts.font.size == null) opts.font.size = 12;
    if (opts.font.color == null) opts.font.color = '#900';
    if (opts.font.shadowColor == null) opts.font.shadowColor = '#aaa';
    if (opts.font.shadowRadius == null) opts.font.shadowRadius = 1;
    if (opts.font.shadowOffset == null) opts.font.shadowOffset = {};
    if (opts.font.shadowOffset.x == null) opts.font.shadowOffset.x = 0;
    if (opts.font.shadowOffset.y == null) opts.font.shadowOffset.y = 1;

    var mainHolder = Ti.UI.createView({
        left: options.left,
        right: options.right,
        top: options.top,
        bottom: options.bottom,
        width: opts.size + opts.margin,
        height: opts.size + opts.margin,
        borderRadius: (opts.size + opts.margin) / 2,
        backgroundColor: opts.backgroundColor
    });

    var holder = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: opts.size,
        height: opts.size,
        borderRadius: opts.size / 2
    });


    var layer1 = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: opts.size,
        height: opts.size,
        borderRadius: opts.size / 2,
        backgroundColor: opts.progressColor
    });

    var layer2 = Ti.UI.createView({
        left: 0,
        width: opts.size / 2,
        height: opts.size,
        anchorPoint: {
            x: 1,
            y: 0.5
        },
        backgroundColor: opts.backgroundColor
    });

    var layer3 = Ti.UI.createView({
        right: 0,
        width: opts.size / 2,
        height: opts.size,
        anchorPoint: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0.5
        },
        backgroundColor: opts.backgroundColor
    });

    var layer4 = Ti.UI.createView({
        right: 0,
        width: opts.size / 2,
        height: opts.size,
        anchorPoint: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0.5
        },
        backgroundColor: opts.progressColor
    });

    var topper = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: opts.topper.size,
        height: opts.topper.size,
        borderRadius: opts.topper.size / 2,
        backgroundColor: opts.topper.color
    });

    var percentText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        visible: opts.font.visible,
        width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        color: opts.font.color,
        font: {
            fontSize:opts.font.size
        },
        shadowColor: opts.font.shadowColor,
        shadowRadius: opts.font.shadowRadius,
        shadowOffset: {
            x: opts.font.shadowOffset.x,
            y: opts.font.shadowOffset.y
        },
        textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        text: (opts.percent * 100) + '%'
    });

    mainHolder.add(holder);
    topper.add(percentText);    
    holder.add(layer1);
    holder.add(layer2);
    holder.add(layer3);
    holder.add(layer4);
    holder.add(topper);

    var percent = opts.percent;
    var angle = 360 * percent;
    layer2.visible = (angle > 180) ? false : true;
    layer4.visible = (angle > 180) ? true : false;
    layer3.transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(angle);
    return mainHolder;  
}

/* Circular Progress Bar Options

 percent: A value between 0 and 1
 size: The size of the circular progress bar
 margin: The margin of the circular progress bar
 backgroundColor: The backgroundColor of the circular area
 progressColor: The backgroundColor of the progress bar
 --
 topper.color: The center circle color
 topper.size: The size of the center circle
 ---
 font.visible: Boolean to display the font or not
 font.color: The font color
 font.size: The fontSize
 font.shadowColor: The font shadow color
 font.shadowRadius: The font shadow radius
 font.shadowOffset.x: The x value of the shadow shadowOffset
 font.shadowOffset.y: The y value of the shadow shadowOffset

 */
var circleProgress1 = circularProgressBar({
    top:50,
    percent:0.35,
    size:46,
    margin:4,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    progressColor:'#4ba818',
    topper: {
        color:'#fff',
        size: 36
    },
    font: {
        visible: true,
        color: '#900',
        size: 12,
        shadowColor: '#aaa',
        shadowRadius: 1,
        shadowOffset: {
            x: 0,
            y: 1
        }
    }
});
win.add(circleProgress1);
```

All that ^^^ creates this:

[image: titanium circular progress bar]

edit: The method I used to create this was from Malcom's idea from this thread: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154274/is-there-a-way-to-create-circular-progress-bar

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not tested it yet... but I will test it within few days because I am off from office. Thanks :)

Comment: I found out that this code DOES work on android. The problem right now is `anchorPoint` as of `Ti SDK 3.2.0`, it is broken. Switching the SDK back to `3.1.3` it works fine. We are currently on `3.2.1` and it is still broken

Comment: @SiddharthVyas all the if statements at the top of the function..those are the options

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a progress bar at all - its an "Activity Indicator".

It doesn't show true progress like a progress bar. With a progress bar, you can set a value for your progress (0-100%, for example). This will just "spin" to let users know that they need to wait.

To create an activity indicator, see here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator

Quick example:

```
var activityView = Ti.UI.createView({visible: false});
var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
  message: 'Loading...',
  height:'auto',
  width:'auto'
});
activityView.add(activityIndicator);
activityView.show();
```

This example will work, but its not styled. I'll leave it up to you to decide how you want it to look. Tho if you want it to look anything like the image you posted, look at backgroundColor, borderRadius, and transparency on the view property.

Comment: I am sure what is displayed in the picture is actually a progress bar, it will fill up to a full circle

Comment: Did you take that screenshot, or find it? If its running in your local simulator, you could look at the source (or link to the source here) and we may can help you further. The only other option I would know of, it to have a bunch of images representing each percent (1.png,2.png,3.png....98.png,99.png,100.png) and just manually change the image on progress.

Comment: Keep in mind, this very well MAY be a control that is useable in xcode with a custom made control - and in that case it could be made into a module for titanium. But, as it stands, I dont know of a way (other then mentioned above) to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't wish Activity Indicator, I wanted it a smooth circular progressbar, but i was looking to create it with Native Titanium development. But I found that Javascript is not getting context for Button, View, etc. And by the way Activity Indicator will not be styled with all those properties included with Titanium.

Comment: Im not sure what your trying to say... but the answer is simple: It doesn't exist in titanium without making it yourself.

Comment: Si vero... That's why I put my question here to get some ideas